# How to Move Yumi Arm to predifined position?

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a project that requires taking images from camera and doing some process and extract the real coordinates and send them to the robot arm.
I was able to do all the camera part, also I was able to connect my ABB yumi Robot to ROS server and I'm able to get the state of both arms and move both arms using MOVEIT+Rviz (random valid motion) using Yumi package from orebro university
My question is that how to make the arms moving to a specific coordinates using the MOVEIT+Rviz or even writing a C++ code to make the arms move to those coordinates.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276780/how-to-move-yumi-arm-to-predifined-position?/) by [Ahmad](https://answers.ros.org/users/32189/ahmad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, I developed what you're basically trying to do in MATLAB. I'm using as well the ABB Yumi.
I  detect some objects using a camera, then I find the position of these objects and eventually I create a trajectory to grasp and move the selected object.
The trajectory I create are for the end-effector, then I convert it into joint trajectories using the inverse kinematic algorithm (it's inside MATLAB). Finally I can send the trajectory to ROS and the robot using the specific Rosaction.

I hope it's helpful.

---

Originally posted by [Marcolino](https://answers.ros.org/users/38940/marcolino/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmed ali 95](https://answers.ros.org/users/53435/ahmed-ali-95/) on 2020-05-02**:
@Marcolino, can I get some guidance from you regarding this work as I am also working on the almost the same project with different application?